# Link not working in yahoo mail

Tags: java, email

While sending email from java to Yahoo mail , the link inside is not working.
URL not clickable in Yahoo while it's fine in Gmail.

Here's code to send the mail:

```
MimeMessage mime = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mime, true);
message.setTo(to);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText("verification link: http://localhost:8080/myproject/verification.zulverId=6c1", true);
this.mailSender.send(mime);
```

Comment: GMail most likely does that automatically. You would have to send a HTML mail and use the tag `<a>` to make it a "real" link

Comment: Yes it worked with <a> tag. Looks like gmail convert url to link but not other email clients. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    message.setContent("verification link: http://localhost:8080/myproject/verification.zulverId=6c1", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    message.saveChanges();
```

setText internally calls setContent method.So use it directly.